# How to make an editable textView to enter in a cell but we can scroll a  datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

I take a datagridveiw  ..in which I make a datagrid in that no one can edit a cells but they can scroll a scrollbar.

I can not used `ENABLE` property..b'cs in it I can not scroll ....

I used **v s 2008**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to build a `DataGridView` which can be scrolled but not editted.  If so then use the `ReadOnly` property

```
myDataGridView.ReadOnly = True
```

Documentation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly.aspx